# Filtering rows that does not contain a string in PYSPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
search = search.filter(!F.col("Name").contains("ABC"))

search = search.filter(F.not(F.col("Name").contains("ABC"))
```

Both methods fail due to syntax error could you please help me filter rows that does not contain a certain string in pyspark.

^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 5):

In a column expression,

```
search.filter(~col("Name").contains("ABC"))
```

where `~` is for the `not` condition.